# My most recent expensive query is sp_procedure_param_rowset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, parameter

I'm stress testing our software running many transactions and reports at the same time on one same DB. analyzing the most recent expensive queries, I found that the top query is the sp_procedure_param_rowset.  Research on sp_procedure_param_rowset shows me that it is when an API calls a Stored procedure and get the metadata of the parameters of each stored procedure.
What I'm trying to figure out and I can't find: 
1. Is this the same as parameter Sniffing issue? 
2. how can I minimize the impact of Sp_procedure_param_rowset?

It's an undocumented system procedure...

Please help
thank you
John

Comment: Does your app have `set nocount on` ? see [this SSC article](http://mailer1.red-gate.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/reducingroundtripspart3/621/)

Comment: Is your app using OLE DB? It seems the app code is requesting parameter meta data on each call. I think that can be eliminated by passing the known strongly-typed parameter collection rather than asking for the definition on each call.

Comment: @dan-guzman We are using Delphi's SDAC.  What do you mean by passing the know strongly-typed parameter collection?  would you have an example?

Comment: @Kin We use Delphi's SDAC, I read the article you pointed me to, but not sure I understand it... I'm not a programmer... I will discuss oit with the developpers to see if they understand it...

Comment: Just spoke to the developer, It seems that our reporting engine calls for the definition of every Stored Procedure before passing the parameters.  I have asked them to change that but not sure how they will be doing it.

Comment: @JohnG, avoiding the request for parameter meta-data will avoid the extra round trip. I haven't used Delphi for 20 years so I can't speak to specifics, but the app code simply needs to pass parameters with data types matching that expected by the proc.